# Finding a Set based on Bit Occurence

Tags: algorithm, set-theory

I am trying to find a column of bits that appears more than once. Let me present you with an example:

> ```
>        X Y Z   
> Set A  0 1 0
> Set B  0 0 1
> Set C  0 1 0
> Set D  0 0 0
> ```

Through a UNION operation, I am able to know which COLUMN from the list of sets has its bit set to 1. If I do A UNION B UNION C UNION D then we get **0 1 1**, which means Column X has no bits set to 1 and Columns Y and Z has AT LEAST 1 of the bits set to 1.

My problem is I'm trying to find the right set operation to find columns that has bits set to 1 more than once. With the above given example, Column Y has 2 bits set to 1. Thus the result should be **0 1 0**.

I tried doing intersections which is the most logical thing to do but produces a different result.

I appreciate is someone could guide me what combination of set operations should I perform to get the desired result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Algorithm" is not a programming language we can help you with. What code are you intending to write here?

Comment: @tadman I'm not attempting to write a code through a programming language but rather I am finding an algorithm (steps) to solve the problem through set theory/operations.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming problems, so if this is more of a mathematical/theoretical thing then it's off-topic here. You may want to try [Quora](https://www.quora.com).

Comment: I don't know how to go about creating a deterministic algorithm from this, but one speculation that might help- you can take the symmetric difference between each set and with the union of all sets, and any bits set to 1 signify an even number of sets with those bits set to 1 (so effectively 50% accuracy). In your example, you would get `A SYM-DIFF B ... SYM-DIFF (A UNION B ...) => 0 1 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is I'm trying to find the right set operation to find columns that has bits set to 1 more than once.

Here's one way:

> (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C) ∪ (A ∩ D) ∪ (B ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ D) ∪ (C ∩ D)

That said, math is pretty flexible; you can literally just say "the set containing all elements that appear in at least two of the sets *A*, *B*, *C*, *D*", and mathematicians will accept that for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Let `USet_0 := 0 0 0` and `DSet_0 := 0 0 0`. We then define

```
USet_(k+1) := USet_k UNION Set_k | forall 0 <= k < n
```

and

```
DSet_(k+1) := DSet_k UNION (USet_k INTERSECT Set_k) | forall 0 <= k < n
```

The operation of finding the union of all your `n` sets then yields `USet_n`. Any columns which have multiple bits set are then represented by `DSet_n`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more fun when you try to do it efficiently.

Assign numbers sequentially to each set, starting at 0.

Then, if there is a column that is in at least two different sets, then the numbers of those two sets must be different, and if the numbers are different, then the binary representation of those numbers will differ in at least one bit position.

So:

1. For each bit position **b** in the set numbers (there are log(number_of_sets) of them):

   1. Create the union of all the sets that have bit **b** set in their numbers;
   2. Create the union of all sets that do *not* have bit **b** set in their numbers;
   3. Intersect those two sets.
2. Create the union of all those intersections.

Done.  The result is the set of all columns that appear in at least 2 different sets.

For example, if column is in both set **5** and set **7**, then it will be in the intersection for bit position **b=1** (place value 2), because the binary representations of **5** **(101)** and **7** **(111)** are different in that bit position.  The column will be in the union of all sets with numbers that have bit **1** off, *and* in the union of all sets that have bit **1** on.

The total number of set operations required is **N*log(N)**, where **N** is the number of sets.